# Why does Godot not respond when I run my program?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am following a tutorial of how to make Flappy Bird in Godot to build my understanding on GDScript and how to use Godot. So far, I have created a character (a KinematicBody2D node) and a script (Player.gd). Player.gd contains the following code:
[An image of the script I made for my character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw4nR.png)

```
extends KinematicBody2D


# Declare member variables here.
const UP = Vector2(0,-1)
const FLAP = 200
const MAXFALLSPEED = 200
const GRAVITY = 10

var motion = Vector2() # this variable is a controller for the direction and position that the player is going in.

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

func _physics_process(delta):
    motion.y += GRAVITY
    if motion.y > MAXFALLSPEED:
        motion.y = MAXFALLSPEED
```

However, when I run my code, my character does not move, and this is what I see:
[My error screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BZUS.png)

I was hoping that with the script Player.gd, the charcter would obey the laws of gravity and slowly fall down to the bottom the screen (as shown in the video, but it doesn't do that. I do not know if it has something to do with the main scene, or just something to do with an error within the game itself which I have overlooked. I have tried everything but have not succeeded in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `motion` variable doesn't do anything on its own. If you want a KinematicBody to move you have to call `move_and_slide()` or a similar function in `KinematicBody2D`

Comment: Where would I put move_and_slide? Would I put it as equal to the motion variable? If so, what arguments would I use? @SilicDev

Comment: `move_and_slide()` needs to be called every iteration step and takes a velocity and an up direction as arguments. Generally speaking though you should look for these things in the documentation. Either searching `godot3 KinematicBody2D` in google or hitting F1 in the editor and searching `KinematicBody2D` there should get you there.